# Simple coldfusion pass record id to JS function?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, cfml

Im trying to pass the unique database session id through cfm pages but cannot seem to get it working. Page 1 has the record id, im trying to save in numSession in the recordclick() function and pass it in the next page, where I use it in my query, but its not working.

Heres a rough outline of what im doing:

Page 1:

```
<CFQUERY datasource = "database1" result = "result">
insert into user
set
blah blah
</cfquery>

<html>
<head>   
<title>page1</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function recordClick(imageid)
{
        document.getElementById("numSend").value =       document.getElementById("numSend").value + imageid;
        document.getElementById("numSession").value = result.generated_key;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<FORM action="page2.cfm" method="post">

<img src="1.png" NAME="num1" onclick="recordClick(1)"
    width="100px"
    height="100px"> 
<div name="num1" id="num1"></div>

<input type="hidden" id="numSend" name="numSend" />
<input type ="hidden" id = "numSession" name ="numSession" />
<input type="submit" value="Done" />
</form>

</body>
</html>

--------------------------------------

<cfoutput>
The ID of the row I just inserted was "#numSession#"
</cfoutput>


<CFQUERY datasource = "database1">
update user
set
pin = "#numSend#"
where id= "#numSession#"
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 6):

ColdFusion is executed on the server, JavaScript is executed on the client. Your JS has no idea what `result` is.

You need to use [ColdFusion's `ToScript()` function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e9d.html).

> **Description**
>
> Creates a JavaScript or ActionScript expression that assigns the value
>   of a ColdFusion variable to a JavaScript or ActionScript variable.
>   This function can convert ColdFusion strings, numbers, arrays,
>   structures, and queries to JavaScript or ActionScript syntax that
>   defines equivalent variables and values.

Here's an example, taken from the docs:

```
<cfset thisString="hello world">
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    <cfoutput>
        var #ToScript(thisString, "jsVar")#;
    </cfoutput>
</script>
```

Your code (corrected):

```
function recordClick(imageid)
{
    var <cfoutput>#ToScript(result.generated_key, "generated_key")#;</cfoutput>
    var objNumSend = document.getElementById("numSend");
    objNumSend.value = objNumSend.value + imageid;
    document.getElementById("numSession").value = generated_key;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but see when I try to output the variable in the second page it doesnt seems to work. second page: <cfoutput> #numSession# </cfoutput>

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific than `doesn't seem to work`

Comment: @user1228554, I've updated the JS function to include the `<cfoutput>` tag. Did that fix your issue?

Comment: What it is, is, on the second page, which im trying to pass the numSession to, it doesnt seem to have the value (record id) in the variable. So it doesnt even print the session id im trying to pass...Page 2 code:                                             <cfoutput>
The ID of the row I just inserted was "#numSession#"
</cfoutput>


<CFQUERY datasource = "database1">
update user
set
pin = "#numSend#"
where id= "#numSession#"
</cfquery>

Comment: @user1228554, you're using a form post, are you qualifying the output with the form scope? You code should look like this: `...where id= "#FORM.numSession#"`

Comment: In 2018, is this still considered "best practice" or a "code smell?"  I'm aware that just because I CAN do this doesn't mean I SHOULD...